# React Native Router Process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native application, I want to create Footer and Tab menu that are valid for some screens and not on some screens. When I define it inside the NavigationContainer, it applies to all screens, but I could not manage to separate it. How can I do it? Frankly I'm trying to create a screen that will open like a full-screen Modal. I will be able to return to the previous screen with a drag, not a click.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Router = () => {

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Topbar />
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {/* Main Screen */}
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Dashboard} options={{ headerShown: false, cardStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.white } }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ProductDetail" component={ProductDetailPage} options={{ headerShown: false, cardStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.white } }} />
      </Stack.Navigator >
      <FooterMenu />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom `header` and `tabBar`. For a modal screen set `presentation` to `modal` and hide the header. Something like this:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={() => <FooterMenu/>} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{header: () => <TopBar/>}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} options={{ presentation: 'modal', headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```